# Remove an ObjectId from an array of objectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, lodash

I have an objectId like this:
`["56153e4c2040efa61b4e267f","56033932efefe0d8657bbd9e"]` 
To save that information in my model I use:

```
items: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Items'
}]
```

What I'm trying to do is to pull an element of the array that is equal to objectId that I send from the front end in a delete request.

The code I'm using:

```
_.remove(unit.items, request.params.itemId);
```

I'm using lodash library.

The problem I suppose is that the array have ObjectId elements and I'm trying to compare with an string that is the request.params.itemId.

Comment: Are you trying to remove an array from an array, or do you have an array of documents, and you want to remove the one matching your req.params.itemId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a very similar setup with an "Event" object that has an array of "Assignment" objects saved as an array of ObjectIds. I was able to simply use

```
obj.arrayField.remove(idToRemove);
```

Here is the relevant code inside of my delete route handler:

```
var id = req.assignment._id;
req.event.assignments.remove(id);
req.event.save(function(err, event) {
    //etc 
}
```

Does this work for you?

```
unit.items.remove(request.params.itemId);
```

Comment: Thanks @MosheKarmel, works great, now if I want to make a difference let say I have an array oldItems = ["56153e4c2040efa61b4e267f","56033932efefe0d8657bbd9e"] and another array newItems =["56033932efefe0d8657bbd9e"], I'm trying to use lodash difference function like this, _.difference(oldItems, newItems) but the result is ["56153e4c2040efa61b4e267f","56033932efefe0d8657bbd9e"]. What I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really know lodash :( Can you mark my answer as correct if I answered the question? You can try asking that as a new question...

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the string into `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('')` to get an actual object you can compare against.

So `_.remove(unit.items, mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.itemId));`